# Connecting User inputted Data into array's in Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf

Im creating a text based game in C, which uses user input to determine rooms and creatures. Rooms can only have 4 doors max, north south east and west, and creatures will eventually be associated to rooms I'd like to take the user input and store it in my struct array(s) as a means to easily connect rooms and creatures.

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */

struct Rooms {
  int roomProperties[5];
};

struct Creatures {
  int creatureProperties[2];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  //creates rooms from user input
  int roomNums;

  printf("Enter rooms ");
  scanf("%d", &roomNums);
  printf("rooms declared %d\n", roomNums);

  //defines room properties with correlation to numbers entered
  int roomState;
  int northRoom;
  int southRoom;
  int eastRoom;
  int westRoom;

  //cycles for input until properties = # of rooms
  for (int i = 0; i < roomNums; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &roomState, &northRoom, &southRoom,    &eastRoom, &westRoom);
    printf("stuff declared %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", roomState, northRoom, southRoom, eastRoom, westRoom);
  }

//spawns creatures based on user input

  int monsterCount;
  printf("Enter Monsters ");
  scanf("%d", &monsterCount);
  printf("monsters declared %d\n", monsterCount);

  //creature properties with correlation to numbers entered
  int creatureType;
  int creatureLocation;

  //prompts for information to match creatures spawned
  for (int j = 0; j < monsterCount; j++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &creatureType, &creatureLocation);
    printf("monster stuff %d, %d\n", creatureType, creatureLocation);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Im trying to connect `roomState`, `northRoom`, `southRoom`, `eastRoom`, and `westRoom` to the struct `Rooms`, specifically `roomState` --> `roomProperties[0]`, and so forth. Im not sure how to go about that.

Comment: For each room struct you could use north, south, east, and west pointers to corresponding room structs.